# django in docker compose don't see posgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I have a problem with my django + postgresql docker compose.

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env
  web:
    build: .
    command: python MoreEnergy/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./MoreEnergy/:/MoreEnergy/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine

WORKDIR /app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev

# install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt


# copy project
COPY . .
```

db container check:

```
(shell) $ docker compose exec db psql --username=dmitriy --dbname=more_energy_db

psql (12.0)
Type "help" for help.

more_energy_db=# \l
                                  List of databases
      Name      |  Owner  | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |  Access privileges  
----------------+---------+----------+------------+------------+---------------------
 more_energy_db | dmitriy | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 postgres       | dmitriy | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 template0      | dmitriy | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/dmitriy         +
                |         |          |            |            | dmitriy=CTc/dmitriy
 template1      | dmitriy | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/dmitriy         +
                |         |          |            |            | dmitriy=CTc/dmitriy
(4 rows)

more_energy_db=#
```

error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

As you can see, db container works correct, but web container don't see database. My .env file has all needed vars to up containers What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see your env for your Django app, but based on your error, I think its because you are trying to connect to the postgres(port 5432) **inside your django container** (127.0.0.1), which is not present there of course.

The thing you should do is set your Django app `env` to connect to your `db` container like this for example `db:5432` (inside the env) (usually accessible using service name within same compose file)

More details about this can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

Answer (score -1):

You have to set host = localhost in your settings.py, as according to create service inside you docker file.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost'
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting the database host name as `localhost` _causes_ this error.